# How to create database list for every user with a different username and being capable of multiple people on at the same time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make an app and it uses databases, the problem or the wall I ran into is i can only have one connection at a time and not multiple otherwise it will give and error and not work. And i have the username stored in one variable which is `var user = "";` and can only have one connection at a time.

```
var user = "";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    person: String,
    date: String,
    loc: String,
    title: String,
    passage: String,
    file: String
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const Item = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
    person: user,
    date: "String",
    loc: "String",
    title: "String",
    passage: "String",
    file: "String"
});

const defaultItems = [item1];

//item1.save();
// user1.save();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    res.render("home");

});

app.get("/loading", function (req, res) {

    res.render("loading");

});

app.get("/signup", function (req, res) {

    res.render("signup");

});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {

    res.render("login");

});

app.get("/workspace", function (req, res) {

    Item.find({ person: user }, function (err, foundItems) {

        if (foundItems.length == 0) {
            Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Added items");
                }
            });
            res.redirect("/workspace");

        } else {
            res.render("workspace", { itemList: foundItems });
        }
    });


});

app.post("/login", function (req, res) {

    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                if (foundUser.password == password) {
                    console.log("Loged In");
                    res.redirect("/workspace");
                    user = email;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

app.post("/signup", function (req, res) {

    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const User1 = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

    const user2 = new User1({
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
        email: email,
        password: password,
    });

    user2.save();

    user = email;

    console.log("Done");

    res.redirect("/workspace");
});

app.post("/workspace", function (req, res) {

    const date = req.body.input1;
    const location = req.body.input2;
    const title = req.body.input3;
    const passage = req.body.input4;
    const file = req.body.input5;

    const item = new Item({
        person: user,
        date: date,
        loc: location,
        title: title,
        passage: passage,
        file: file
    });

    item.save();

    res.redirect("/workspace");
});
```

Is there a way to be able to have multiple people connected and using the app at the same time and having a different database for each user?

Answer (score 0):

A rough idea.

While establishing the MongoDB connection, generate a unique ID for each visitor and change the name of DB as per the ID. Please refer below code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuid     = require('uuid');
const dbName   = uuid();
// connecting to mongo database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/' + dbName, { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false ,useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to database.');
    }
});
```

It will create a new DB name, for each new visitor. It might not be the best solution.

Comment: Hi what i was meaning was, i want the user once it has logged in it will open his collection in the database. I have sort of worked it out but i can only have one connection at a time for some reason.